# Display an error message for the non-numeric input

Tags: java

So this is my code i dont know what to add if i want to display invalid message for the non numeric inputs please help ty

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Date
{
public static void main (String args [])
{
    int x;
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a date ");
x = in.nextInt();


while (x < 1520 || x > 3999)
{
System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
x = in.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Good");
```

Comment: That's awful, incomplete and missing indentation. I'd advise you to fix this first.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch block, and put `x = in.nextInt();` inside it

Comment: i now have while loop where will i need to add it?

Comment: This is a poorly explained answer.  You'd put `in.nextInt()` inside a `try{}` block.  The `catch{}` block will handle the error if the user types something that's not an int.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner class has [a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) for this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x;
if(in.hasNextInt()){
  x = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Valid number");
}else{
  System.out.println("Not a number");
}
```

To keep prompting until a valid number is entered

```
int x;
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

while(!in.hasNextInt()){
  System.out.println("Invalid number, try again: ");
  key.nextLine(); // Flush out invalid number
}

x = key.nextInt();
```

Comment: im new in java and i dont understand your code with "key" thing so maybe you can use my code to put that then? can you sir?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit. I think this is what you were aiming for.

I'm not that good in explaining but I try to tell what I did.

First of all I got rid of your `in.nextInt()` since this is very restrictive. It does only accept an integer and will throw an exception if you type something else in. Normally this would be OK, but since you want the user to be able to correct the input, this will cause more troubles than it would solve.

I then put your code into an infinite loop `while(true)` which assures, you do not have to restart your application again once you've typed in a wrong value.

What is going on within the loop is quite simple. The console prints out what you want the user to do and reads the consoles input as a String, so you don't have to face any exceptions in the first place.
I then try to parse the given String into an integer value. I added `trim()` to kill leading spaces as well as trailing, so I won't have to deal with users being confused by typing in numbers with a space since they don't directly see whats wrong when getting their "not an integer" error. This would be thrown, if the input contains spaces.

Now I check whether or not the given integer-value fits your specifiation. I don't need a loop here, so I changed it to be a simple if-statement.
If the value is wrong (or lets say the `if (x < 1520 || x > 3999)` returns true) I'm going to print out your error message. Since we already passed casting the String input into the integer and we do not reach the `else`-branch we now return back to the beginning of our loop with printing out the request again before waiting for a new input to be made.

Now, as soon as the user typed in another value, e.g. 2011 (which is valid based on your specification) we will now reach the else-branch which prints the "Good" and leaves the loop by calling `break`. And since there is nothing left to do for the application it will stop running. If you want the user to be able to type in new values in the positive case, you simply have to remove the `break`-statement.

If the user types in a value which is not an integer, the cast will fail and throw a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). We catch this exception by surrounding the cast with the `try-catch`-block and print out the integer-error once we've reached the catch-block.

Then the application reacts the same way like if you typed in a wrong number and we will return to the beginning of the loop again.

The reason for putting a try-block around the Scanner is to [handle closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String input = "";
        int x = 0;
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);) {

            while (true) {

                System.out.print("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
                input = in.nextLine();

                try {
                    x = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());

                    if (x < 1520 || x > 3999) {

                        System.out.println("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Good");
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Given value \"" + input.trim() + "\" is not an integer.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to teach the asker something, instead of just handing them code/doing it for them.